# Find all documents in mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to display all documents **(select *)** with sub-documents in PHP.

I know how to query all `find()` but I have no idea how to do it when I have sub-documents. I don't know if there's something like `find()` or I need to make loops fo every sub-documents that I'd have.

This would be the code

```
$mongodatabase->insertOne(
    ['name' => 'Alex',
    'surname' => 'Turner',
    'country' => 'England',
    'birth' => array(
        'day' => 6,
        'month' => 'january',
        'year' => 1986
    ),
]);
```

Something easy, just to learn. When I try a `var_dump` of day I get Undefined index and NULL.

```
$client = new MongoDB\client;
$db = $client->database;
$mongodatabase = $db->document;
$document = $mongodatabase->find();

foreach ($document as $doc) {
     var_dump($doc->day);
}
```

However, I'd like to query all.

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Do not edit the word "solved" in to the question title. Accepting an answer is how you mark a question as successfully answered.

Comment: @Quentin well, I thought remarking as [SOLVED] in the title it would be an easily search for those new users (or even not users) who are looking for same answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) - It helps us in identifying the elements which are not empty

```
db.collection_name.find({
   "birth.day" : { 
      $exists : true
   }
});
```

If you need to check not null and empty, then we need to use [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) together with [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/), [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) can be passed with different values and 10 is for null check

```
db.collection_name.find({
   "birth.day" : { 
      $not : { $type : 10 },
      $exists : true
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when u find the exactly data from mongoldb u can use the shelter to limit the field 
eg:

```
db.xxxxx.find(
    {'status':'DELIVRD'}
);
```